# How do I make a currency calculations based on rounded times?

Tags: swiftui

I have SwiftUI code which computes the time duration between two times (startTime and endTime) and rounds up to nearest 15 minutes.  But how do I calculate the currency rate of $220 per hour from this duration?

I also seem to be struggling with organizing my code into view code (for SwiftUI) and also including the numerical code that runs in the background.

But here's my code I have so far with comments where I need to include this code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var startTime = Date().zeroSeconds
    @State private var endTime = Date().zeroSeconds
    @State private var number15Intervals = 0
    @State private var amountDue = 0.0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Enter Case Times:")) {
                    DatePicker("Start Time", selection: $startTime , displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    DatePicker("End Time", selection: $endTime, in: startTime..., displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Case Duration:")) {
                    Text("duration = \(self.duration) min")
                    Text("duration (15m) = \(self.duration15) min")
                }
                Section(header: Text("Amount Due:")) {
                    
 //        What code do I put here to calculate currency (US dollars)
//         which equals time (rounded up by 15 min) times a rate of $220 per hour?
                    
                    Text(amountDue, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currencyCode ?? "USD"))
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("DDA Rates Calculator")
        }
    }
    
    var duration: TimeInterval {
        guard endTime > startTime else {
            return 0
        }
        let dateIntervalMinutes = DateInterval(start: startTime, end: endTime).duration / 60
        return dateIntervalMinutes
    }
    
    var duration15: TimeInterval {
        return  (self.duration/15.0).rounded(.up)*15
    }
}

extension Date {
    var zeroSeconds: Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: self)
        return calendar.date(from: dateComponents) ?? self
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Sorry if I'm not too clear here.  I've tried all sorts of ways to do this but always seem to get all sorts of errors from XCode.  I think it would be more confusing to show what I've tried so far since I tried it so many ways without success.  I'm not understanding the scope and how to reference variables properly in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `amountDue` `@State` variable with a computed property:

```
var amountDue: Double {
    duration15 / 60 * 220
}
```

(You can also remove the unused `number15Intervals`)

Comment: How would I return $460 if duration15 < 1 hour and $300 / hour if > 6 hours?

Comment: You can write an `if` statement within the property. You can describe the case you just laid out there. Have you given it a shot?

Comment: Yes, I tried if statement but all sorts of errors.  I tried this:     var amountDue: Double {
        if duration15 < 60 {
            return 460.
        } else {
            duration15 / 60 * 220
        }
    }. How do I show code in a comment?

Comment: You have an extra `.` in there